# Capture picture from video using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

I am trying to capture a picture from a video on my iPad. I used Apple's AVCam example as a starting point.

I was able to see the video in my application and to take pictures from it. My problem is that the pixel size of the result image is wrong. I want a fullscreen picture (1024x768) but I get a smaller one (1024x720).

Those are my instance variables:

```
@property (retain) AVCaptureStillImageOutput *stillImageOutput;
@property (retain) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer;
@property (retain) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@property (retain) AVCaptureConnection *captureConnection;
@property (retain) UIImage *stillImage;
```

Here the code to take pictures:

```
- (void)takePicture
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in [[self stillImageOutput] connections]) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", [self stillImageOutput]);
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                                         completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                                             CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment(imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
                                                             if (exifAttachments) {
                                                                 NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
                                                             } else {
                                                                 NSLog(@"no attachments");
                                                             }
                                                             NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
                                                             UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                                                             [self setStillImage:image];
                                                             [image release];
                                                             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kImageCapturedSuccessfully object:nil];
                                                         }];
}
```

I thought of resizing the final picture but this solution would decrease the quality of the image.
I also realized that the `CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments` dictionary contains a value `PixelYDimension = 720;` but I can't seem to find a way to interact with it.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you in advance and have a nice day,

Alex.

**EDIT:** I'd like to point out that when I say "taking a picture from a video" I meant that the video is coming live from the iPad's camera and **it is not** a recording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Here it goes in case someone looks for this in the future.

To interact with the camera using AVFoundation we need to initiate a `AVCaptureSession` variable.
After doing this we can modify the [sessionPreset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVCaptureSession/sessionPreset) indicating the quality level or bitrate of the output.
There are a [set of different constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Video_Input_Presets). To take 1024x768 pictures I used `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`