# AVCaptureSession specify custom resolution

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, avfoundation, avcapturesession

does anybody know how to set a custom resolution in a custom iOS camera using AVFoundation (AVCaptureStillImageOutput)?

I know you can select a preset using AVCaptureSession, but I need an output resolution of 920x920 (not provided by a preset). Currently I use AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh and resize the UIImage after but that seems silly and a lot extra, unnecessary processing.

Comment: There is no way to capture at a custom resolution as far as I am aware. You will have to scale it yourself, and then encode it in the target format.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but what you can do is iterate through all the `AVCaptureDeviceFormat`s looking for the one closer to your resolution.
To get a complete list of all the available formats, just query the capture device using the property `-formats`.
This example from Apple shows how to pick the best frame rate:

```
- (void)configureCameraForHighestFrameRate:(AVCaptureDevice *)device
{
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *bestFormat = nil;
    AVFrameRateRange *bestFrameRateRange = nil;
    for ( AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format in [device formats] ) {
        for ( AVFrameRateRange *range in format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges ) {
            if ( range.maxFrameRate > bestFrameRateRange.maxFrameRate ) {
                bestFormat = format;
                bestFrameRateRange = range;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( bestFormat ) {
        if ( [device lockForConfiguration:NULL] == YES ) {
            device.activeFormat = bestFormat;
            device.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration;
            device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = bestFrameRateRange.minFrameDuration;
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is about dimensions, not framerate.

Comment: @Emiswelt fra rates and resolution are connected , the posted snippet is just a way to get the device formats. What the OP is asking is if he can do a custom size resolutin and the answer is NO.

Comment: Hi, How can I query the image resolution? I cannot find properties related to that...

Answer (score 0):

Please, check out one of my old questions that I answered myself, it may help you.

[Capture picture from video using AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9683916/capture-picture-from-video-using-avfoundation)

Comment: Thanks, I read that already but unfortunately it doesn't help me; there is no preset for the resolution I need.